# Run exec() Rscript from wordpress install

Tags: php, r, amazon-ec2

**Goal:**
Run a simple Rscript from a wordpress page.

- I'm currently attempting to run an Rscript using exec() upon loading the page. The script creates a histogram of 100 random samples from integers 1 through 10, writes system time to title and saves figure to .png file.

**Setup**:

- Running Wordpress install on Ubuntu EC2 micro instance
- R has been successfully installed and tested through ssh
- Using Exec-PHP Wordpress plugin so that PHP code can be written and executed (tested successfully)

**PHP code (within wordpress Page)**

```
    <?php 
    echo "This is the Exec-PHP 'Hello World'\n"; 
    echo exec("date");
    ?>

    <?php
    exec("Rscript <PATH>/test.R");
    ?>

    <img src="<Image Location>/samplePlot.png" alt="" title="Sample R" />
```

**Rscript - test.R**

```
    png( "<Image Location>/samplePlot.png")
    hist( sample( 1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), main= Sys.time(), lwd = 5)
    dev.off()
```

The image file loads but it is not updated, indicating the Rscript was never executed. I've isolated it down to that being the issue but unsure why that is.

How can I debug this? I don't really know any PHP but I tried the following:

```
    <?php
    exec("\usr\bin\Rscript <PATH>/test.R", $output, $result);
    echo $output;
    echo $result
    ?>
```

Which returns:

```
Array2
```

I was hoping to get the command line output to check for errors. Is this possible?

Comment: does it work as expected from the command line? how long deoes the r script take to run

Comment: It does work when I ssh in as regular user. The script executes very quickly. Could it be an issue with permissions? Unable to write? How would I check this? I've had trouble getting any output from the php exec() call.

Comment: I'd guess the script runs while the HTML is sent to the user, and so they download the old version of the plot while it is being updated

Comment: @hadley I thought that was possible but I checked and the image is never updated at all. I even went into the machine and checked the timestamp. When running the Rscript from the command line this is very clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the problem is that you did not specify the full path to `Rscript` and the user running PHP/Apache just does not know where to search for it.

Update that `exec` command like (on Linux):

```
exec("/usr/bin/Rscript <PATH>/test.R");
```

Anyway, I would suggest installing [littler](http://code.google.com/p/littler/) for the task later and (based on that) runnning `r` instead of `Rscript` for letting things run a lot faster - if installing eg. [rApache](http://rapache.net/) is not an option.

Comment: I originally used the full path and had the same result. I'll look into littler in the meantime.

Comment: Do you have apparmor or similar installed/configured? Try to run `Rcript` in the name of the webserver user from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

To get an idea of the problem try:

```
$e = exec("\usr\bin\Rscript <PATH>/test.R 2>&1");
var_dump($e);
```

If you get something like: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) ... 
you probably need to update the servers dynamic libraries (try searching for libfreetype.dylib), or if your running MAMP (as I am) you need to comment (#) the two uncommented lines in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars

I know it is a long time since you posted the question, but I spend a lot of time with a similar problem - hopefully somebody can save some time ;)

Comment: While not really pertinent for the original question (which referenced running in Ubuntu, not Mac OS X), I gotta say - this ended an hours long search of frustration for me. Even after modifying library file ownership, I could never get MAMP to properly include even the core libraries (like stats), though it would load RJSONIO just fine. Weird. In any event, commenting those lines allowed MAMP executed R scripts to find dylibs it was not finding before that presumably were dependencies of packages like stats. Thanks for sharing!